# hung up at "Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class"

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I keep getting this error

> Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class

from the code below

I'm not sure what is wrong, but any help would be helpful.

It hung up at the `With ....End With` part.

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase,SourceData:="Report1&2!R1C1:R1048576C126", Version:=xlPivoTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="EID_Graph!R1C1",TableName:="PivoTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("ID_1")
  .Orientation = xlRowField
  .Position = 1

End With
```

Comment: Is the active sheet `EID_Graph` ?

Comment: `TableName:="PivoTable1"` when creating the table, but `PivotTables("PivotTable1")` when you use it.

Comment: hi Tim, it was my typo here, it should be correct in the code. I got these coding from recording the macro and paste it in my module. yes EID_Graph is an active sheet. any other idea?

Comment: any help  here would be very appreciated